# WPF How to get to RadioButton's Path, Data properties in a template?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I simply have a radiobutton and a template on it. I want to trigger colors change of background and the Path's Fill property (I use a vector image). Ideally trigger Fill change on IsChecked, but I cannot access that Path by its x:Name...

The template:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}"
                     x:Key="MenuRadioButton">
        <Border x:Name="RadBtnBorder"
                CornerRadius="8">
            <Border.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="RadBtnBorderBackground"
                                 Color="Black" />
            </Border.Background>

            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            Width="24"
                            Height="24"
                            Margin="4">
                <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="VectorImageTemplate">
                        <Path x:Name="Path"
                              Fill="{Binding Fill}"
                              Data="{Binding Data}" />

                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Path"
                                     Property="IsMouseOver"
                                     Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Path"
                                        Property="Fill"
                                        Value="Red" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            </ContentControl>
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="RadBtnBorder"
                        Property="Background"
                        Value="Green" />

            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

A button example:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="RadBtnHome"
             GroupName="Menu"
             Margin="5"
             ToolTip="Text"
             Template="{StaticResource MenuRadioButton}"
             IsChecked="True">
    <RadioButton.Content>
        <Path Fill="White"
              Width="24"
              Height="24"
              Data="M12.89,3L14.85,3.4L11.11,21L9.15,20.6L12.89,3M19.59,12L16,8.41V5.58L22.42,12L16,18.41V15.58L19.59,12M1.58,12L8,5.58V8.41L4.41,12L8,15.58V18.41L1.58,12Z" />
    </RadioButton.Content>
</RadioButton>
```

I tried different approaches like using ContentPresenter and trying to get to properties through classes via '.', but nothings helps.

Comment: It seems odd to have two Path elements here. Consider setting a Geometry as Content and bind the Fill and Data properties of the Path in the ContentTemplate to the Foreground and Content properties of the RadioButton. The Foreground could then be set by a Trigger in the ControlTemplate.

Comment: @Clemens I have several buttons, so I want them to be able to change their Data.

Comment: That's why you would set a Geometry as Content. Geometry is the type of the Data property.